# How to verify a phone number and login using Facebook in Flutter

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

I am developing a mobile application in Flutter, the mobile application should allow the user to verify his phone number first before allowing him to proceed, and we should allow the user to authenticate by Facebook, is there any tutorial or documentation that shows out how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [`firebase_auth` plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth) does this for you. Setting it up you will have to follow the instructions on the page, which also gives a basic example of the functionality.

*Documentation*, sadly, is not really avalaible, but the source is easy to understand (after taking a look at the example in the `Readme.md`). [Here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/firebase_auth.dart#L212) you can take a look at authentication with *Facebook*.

*Phone auth* is currently not completely implemented with the official SDK, so please check the latest replies [to this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10404).